# tensorflow dataset sliding window batch not working?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I cannot get this code to work, where am I wrong?

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(np.arange(8))
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.sliding_window_batch(window_size=4))
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
element = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    while True:
        try:
            print(sess.run(element))
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print('end')
            break
```

I would have expected `[0,1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],...` but instead I get nothing.

EDIT:
if I do `print(dataset)` before `apply` I get `<TensorDataset shapes: (8,), types: tf.int64>`, after `apply` I get `<_SlideDataset shapes: (?, 8), types: tf.int64>`, which is not what I expected: shouldn't the shape of `_SlideDataset` be `(?, 4)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code from `from_tensors` to `from_tensor_slices`. See the code update below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((np.arange(8)))
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.sliding_window_batch(window_size=4))
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
element = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    while True:
        try:
            print(sess.run(element))
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print('end')
            break
```

#### Output:

```
[0 1 2 3]
[1 2 3 4]
[2 3 4 5]
[3 4 5 6]
[4 5 6 7]
end
```